# Fetching all the Module name, class name and method names from directory in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, operating-system

if a directory contains multiple .py files
say, a.py , b.py, c.py
How can i fetch all the module name and their class name and eventually all the method names of the corresponding class, contaned in that directory

Comment: See [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter the files in a directory you can use('.' refers to the current directory):

```
from os import listdir,chdir

default_path = r'c:\dev\python'
modules = [ fl for fl in listdir(default_path) if fl.endswith('.py') ]
```

To get the classes and methods I know you can use inspect though you can't use it without importing the module:

e.g.

```
from inspect import getmembers, isfunction, ismethod, isclass
your_module = __import__(modules[0].split('.')[0])

class_funcs = {}    
funcs = [ obj for obj in getmembers(your_module) if isfunction(obj[1]) ]
classes = [ obj for obj in getmembers(your_module) if isclass(obj[1]) ] 

for cls in classes:
    class_funcs[cls[0]] = [ obj for obj in getmembers(cls[1]) if ismethod(obj[1]) ]

print funcs

[('function1', <function your_module.function1>),
('function2', <function your_module.function2>)]

print class_funcs

{'ClassName': [('__init__', <unbound method ClassName.__init__>),
('Method_name', <unbound method ClassName.Method_name>)]}
```

That will give you all the functions, classes, classes methods in your module.

If you don't want to import the module I'm not familiar with a way to get the methods(except for reading the file and using regex and etc.).

Comment: Can't i use the module name received using the first method you have mentioned and then use it in the 2nd method to fetch the function names ??

Comment: You can. Import the module on the first part like this:
module = __import__('file')

Comment: so when i am doing that it says, import error: no module named Module_name

Comment: You probably need to remove the file extension:
your_module = __import__(module_file_name.split('.')[0])

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to import the modules you could use AST to inspect them.

```
import ast
import _ast

def inspect_module(module_path):
    with open(module_path) as mf:
        tree = ast.parse(mf.read())
    module_classes = [_ for _ in tree.body if isinstance(_, _ast.ClassDef)]
    module_classes = [(c.name, [_.name for _ in c.body if isinstance(_, _ast.FunctionDef)]) for c in module_classes]
    return module_classes
```

It returns a list containing a tuple of the class name and a list of the function names. Unfortunately it does not work for inhereted functions.
It could easily be extended to give you all the arguments for the functions.